# Multiply each row in a matrix by a row vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

I have a matrix A of size `r x c`, `c` is constant but `r` can vary. I have a row vector of length c.

I need to produce a matrix which is product of multiply each row in `A` by the row vector.

I have tried

```
new_matrix = A * row_vector
```

but it returns an error because they aren't the same shape.

Answer (score 3):

use `bsxfun`:

```
bsxfun(@times,A,row_vector)
```